# How to export a svn file using ansible?

Tags: svn, ansible

I tried with `subversion` module it reports as : it is a file not a directory.

Then i used  `command` module

```
svn cat ip/build.xml --username admin --password 1234
```

It works fine.

Is there any other way in ansible for performing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do an `svn export` of a file:

```
- name: svn export file
  subversion:
    export: yes
    repo: https://svn.eionet.europa.eu/repositories/airquality/PP_Command.py
    dest: /tmp/PP_Command.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Below ansible script shows how to export file using subversion.

```
- subversion:
    repo: svn+ssh://an.example.org/path/to/repo
    dest: /src/export
```

more info :http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/subversion_module.html